# Interval for bisection method

Tags: c++, bisection

I've been assigned a project to determine the square root of a number without using division or the math.h library. Upon doing my own research I've decided to tackle the problem by using the bisection method. I used the pseudo code portion from the Bisection Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method#Example:_Finding_the_root_of_a_polynomial

to setup the algorithm.

**My Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;

void __attribute__((weak)) check(double alt_sqrt(double));

//default check function - definition may be changed - will not be graded
void __attribute__((weak)) check(double alt_sqrt(double))
{
    if(alt_sqrt(123456789.0) == sqrt(123456789.0))cout << "PASS\n";
    else cout << "FAIL\n";
    return;
}

//change this definition -  will be graded by a different check function
double my_sqrt(double x)
{
    int i = 0;
    double a = 0.0;         // Lower Bound
    double b = x + 1;       // Upper Bound
    double c = 0.0;         // Guess for square root
    double error = 0.00001;
    double fc = 0.0;
    while(i < 10000)
    {
        c = (a+b)*0.5;
        fc = c * c - x;
        if(abs(fc) < error || (b-a)*0.5 < error)        // Check for solution
        {
            cout << "Square root is: " << c << endl;
            break;
        }
        if(fc < 0)      // Setup new interval
        {
            a = c;
            cout << "a is: " << a << endl;
        }
        else b = c;
        cout << "b is: " << b << endl;
        i++;
    }
    return c;
}

//Do not change this function
int main()
{
    check(my_sqrt);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am currently getting for my professor's test case in main is

```
Square root is: 1.23457e+08
FAIL
```

When the correct output should be

```
Square root is: 11,111.11106
PASS
```

I believe that I am going wrong in the way that I setup my new intervals. My thinking is that if the difference between the two values is negative, then I need to push the lower bound up, and if the difference is positive, then I need to bump the upper bound down.

I would appreciate any advice y'all could give me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: *"without using division"* `*0.5` Trololol. =D Define "division" I guess.

Comment: Perhaps trying your function on a smaller number will allow you to debug it to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Your next choice of interval should be based on whether `c` is positive or negative.

Comment: @mah I've tried using smaller numbers like 9 or 16, but the output is still incorrect. When I was printing out the intervals after each iteration, I found that the upper bound was constantly decreasing, even going past what I knew the actual square root was.

Comment: @ immibis Did you mean fc, the value of the function f(c) = c^2 - x ? As I understand it (and as I've implemented it), c should never be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `fb - fa < 0` is wrong because ignoring floating-point errors, `fa < fb`, which is `a * a - x < b * b < x` will be always true for `0 <= a < b`.

Changing the condition to `fc < 0` improved the accuracy, but unfortunately this improvement coundl't make the program print "PASS". To improve the accuracy to have the program print "PASS", delete the harmful breaking part

```
    if(abs(fc) < error || (b-a)*0.5 < error)        // Check for solution
    {
        cout << "Square root is: " << c << endl;
        break;
    }
```

Removing this harmful breaking and adding the line

```
cout << "Square root is: " << c << endl;
```

just before

```
return c;
```

gave me

```
Square root is: 11111.1
PASS
```

but unfortunately this is not what you want.
To have what you want printed,

```
#include <iomanip>
```

should be added and the printing part should be

```
std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
cout << fixed << setprecision(5) << "Square root is: " << c << endl;
```

Comment: Yes, if PASS or FAIL is determined by a floating-point `==`, iteration must continue until fc == 0.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks for the advice! Could you expand on why I need to compare fc instead of the difference between fb and fa? My train of thought was the that the sign of the difference would indicate which bound I needed to update ( negative requiring the lower bound to update and positive requiring the upper bound to update).

Comment: @Austin Because examining the sign of `fc`, not difference between `fb` and `fa`, is a part of [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).